# Add the accounts avatars and titles to careers profile

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

Yesterday I set up my [Stack Overflow Careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/pareshmayani). It's looking fine and is really helpful to show our activities and knowledge.

But in profile, i found one thing that You have listed all Stack Exchange Accounts below with Accounts name and reputation points of it. So i think if we people get Reputation Photo badge something like [this](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/a20a82d9075b4201b7041b3c4cd167ae.png) to put at the Title of the profile (or below the Photo avator) then it would make a profile much more better than listing all accounts.

Answer (score 2):

The [network flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/a20a82d9075b4201b7041b3c4cd167ae.png) provides less information than the current list of accounts, since it doesn't tell you how active the user is on each site.  For example, [my flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/a6dabf2c938749159097e0d38cd76baa.png) is weighted towards MSO and gaming, which isn't very informative to an employer.

Our biggest problem right now is that we actually give too *little* information on each site -- the average employer doesn't know that 1k rep is on the lower end for SO, but very high for gamedev (for example), so one thing we might add is showing "Top *n*%" to each row to give some context to reputation.

Comment: ya it is there, but we can also display the network flair under the person's photo to show their activity with total reputation and total badges. What you say.

Comment: @PM I think it might be helpful if you created a mockup (even a very basic one) so that we can see exactly what you're proposing.

Comment: there is no means to prepare mockup becoz proposal is already tagged with "status_declined". Thanx, next time i will take care while making proposal or will not put a proposal.

Comment: @PM decisions can be and often are reversed :)  I didn't see any activity for 24 hours, so I figured it was done.